# Filling stalls within an Array ( Big Java Ex 7.22)

Tags: java, divide-and-conquer

For Some background here is the problem statement.

> It is a well-researched fact that men in a restroom generally prefer
> to maximize their distance from already occupied stalls, by occupying
> the middle of the longest sequence of unoccupied places. For example,
> consider the situation where ten stalls are empty.
>
> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ The first visitor will occupy a middle position:
>
> _ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _ The next visitor will be in the middle of the empty area at the left.
>
> _ _ X _ _ X _ _ _ _
>
> Write a program that reads the number of stalls and then prints out diagrams in the format given above when the stalls become filled, one at a time. Hint: Use an array of boolean values toindicate whether a stall is occupied.

I have also found the solution for which I understand for the most part but am having trouble understanding a bit. Here it is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class StallLogic
{
    public void printStalls(boolean [] b)
    {
        for(boolean s:b)
        {
            System.out.print((s?"X" : "_") + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    
    public boolean giveFlag(boolean [] b)
    {
        for(boolean s : b)
        {
            if(!s) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public int getLongest(boolean [] b)
    {
        int length = 0, temp = 0;
        int len = b.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < len ; i++)
        {
            if (b[i] == false)
            {
                temp++;
            }
            else{
                temp = 0;
            }
            if (length < temp)
                length = temp;
        }
        return length;
    }
    
    public int checkIndex(boolean [] b)
    {
        int length = 0 , temp = 0, ind = 0;
        int len = b.length;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        {
            if(b[i] == false)
            {
                temp++;
            }
            else{
                temp = 0;
            }
            if (length < temp)
            {
                ind = i -length;
                length = temp;
            }
        }
        return ind;
    }
    
    public void findStalls(boolean [] b)
    {
        int loc = checkIndex(b);
        int len = getLongest(b);
        int ind = loc + len / 2;
        b[ind] = true;
    }
}

public class checkStall
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    StallLogic stallin = new StallLogic();  
    System.out.print("Enter number of stalls");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = in.nextInt();
    boolean [] stalls = new boolean [i];
    while(!stallin.giveFlag(stalls))    
    {
        stallin.findStalls(stalls);
        stallin.printStalls(stalls);
    }
    
    }

    
}
```

**My Struggles**

I'm having trouble understand what the point of `checkIndex` really is. I understand that `getLongest`, will tell us which parts of the arraylist have the most successive `_`'s

For example in `_ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _` We check that the left side has more `_` with `getLongest`. Now the problem is we need an actual index to put the `X` in. How Will our program know whether to put it on the left side or the right side of every pre-existing X? This is where I PRESUME the `checkIndex` comes in.

Particularly What I am confused about is why I am taking the maximum count of how many _'s there are and adding it with the specific index? I.e `int ind = loc + len / 2;`

What is `checkIndex` and `int ind = loc + len / 2,` exactly doing here? Is there some algorithm for this I am not realizing?

Comment: Seems to be a standard divide-and-conquer algorithm. You don't understand the midpoint formula?

Comment: The point of such an exercise is for you to come up with a solution of your own, not to steal a solution you don't even understand. It's coming up with a solution that teaches you best.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked this question if I didn't try. The whole point of asking is because I couldn't solve it. There is no "stealing"

Comment: ...and when people make accusations without any concrete evidence, it kind of bothers me. I see no way that @Andreas could know about you not understanding the problem. I see code, I see your "Struggles," and I most certainly do NOT see any "stealing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing out the algorithm, it would appear that `getLongest` is returning the length of the longest empty section of stalls.

Then, `checkIndex` gets the left-most empty stall of that same section.

With those two numbers, you simply split the difference, and occupy that stall `left + (length / 2)`.

---

It's a less efficient approach by "scanning" the stalls twice. The `getLongest` and `checkIndex` methods could be combined to return an `int[]` of both positions because the inclusion of `int ind` is the only change between the two methods.

Comment: Why does checkIndex et the left most empty stall? I thought it simply counts the largest amount of _'s that are next to each other? For example _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _   has length 9, _ _ _  _ _ X _ _ _ _  now temp = 5, and it won't care about the temp =4 after the X, since the old temp is 5.

Comment: In the case of `_ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _`, I think `checkIndex` will return 0 while `getLongest` returns 5. You are welcome to debug yourself and check.

Comment: You are correct. I apologize I meant getLongest. I think I get what you are saying, I'll try to trace this program

Comment: Both methods find the longest empty section. One returns the left-most empty position, the other returns the right-most empty position.

Comment: What does this have to do with left and right though? Suppose we have _ _ X _ _ X _ _ _ _, getLongest returns four here since there are more _'s on the right side. Now consider _ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _, there are 5 on the left. Am I just confusing myself?

Comment: That's another approach. I've updated my answer with that explanation.

Comment: Okay, I'm still a bit confused but I'm going to trace the program on paper and see if that helps. Thanks alot

Comment: OoOoOoOooOoO. I get it! This is genius!! Honestly, would have never thought of it!

Comment: Yup. Might have been quicker to trace it on paper instead of going to StackOverflow ;)